# What security attacks is my simple cart system open to?

Tags: web-application, php

I'm putting together a simple site with a basic checkout process. I am using laravel 5.2. When a user makes a visit, the applications checks to see if a cookie is planted with a cookie hash id - the hash is 70 chars long. If there is a cookie, the cart hash is searched for in the database and if found, pulled for the user. If the hash doesn't exist, the cookie is deleted.

If no cookie exists, a new cart is created, stored in teh db, and the hash is stored in a cookie.

A cart contains an array of `cart products`. A cart product contains a unique hash itself.

Cart Products are added to the cart via a route, which contains the product id, and products are removed from the cart by a route which contains the cart item hash.

This is currently on a non-ssl domain.

Is this basic part of the system open to attacks I should be concerned about?

Comment: Letsencrypt.org gives free SSL certs. Logon process needs to be SSL, cookies needs to be secure, then it's worth testing for security. Security is multi-layered so before considering security all layers must be in place.

Comment: @Aria "logon process needs to be SSL", no, **everything** needs to be SSL (or rather, TLS).

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel instead of using Laravel's built-in session mechanism? Just store you cart model's ID in the user's session and let Laravel handle the heavy lifting like cookies.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters have pointed out, you've got some essential work to do (move everything to HTTPS, make the cookies Secure and probably also HttpOnly, etc.) and should avoid reinventing the wheel if possible. Also, you're at risk of all kinds of standard web application security vulnerabilities (cross-site scripting, cross-site request forgery, clickjacking, SSL stripping, etc.); you'll need to be careful of those.

A few specific issues that jump out at me while reading your description:

- SQL injection. If you're looking up the cookie value in a database, that's an obvious injection vector. Use parameterized queries / stored procedures, or at least make very damn sure you validate the cookie's contents before checking the database (don't rely on sanitizing/escaping the cookie; better to just drop it on the floor if it is even slightly incorrectly formed).
- Token prediction. You describe the cookie value as a hash (though I'm not aware of any hash function with a 70-character digest even in hex encoding); what are you hashing? Is it something that an attacker might be able to predict, like some combination of constant values and maybe a sequentially-increasing ID value or the like? If two people have the same things in their cart, are their cookie values the same? If not, what distinguishes them?
- Session fixation / cookie planting. If cookies are used to identify carts (rather than users with payment methods), an attacker could try to add items that the attacker is selling to other peoples' carts, by figuring out what the hash for (for example) a cart with 10 AttackerThings in it is, and then putting that cookie on as many users as possible. Some of them may make their purchase without looking closely at what-all they're buying, causing them to overspend and give the extra (via your store) to the attacker.

Web apps are, unfortunately, really easy to get wrong. Languages like PHP make it easy to develop a web app but don't help secure it (indeed, the PHP language is notorious for all the insecure web apps written by people who think learning PHP means they know everything they need about how to write web apps). Good for you, thinking about security at this point, but you need a lot more than just having the basic business logic be secure.